# Backbone.js Collection Not Adding Objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to fetch a collection data from the server and load it into my collection object, with Backbone.js. I want to fetch these data at the start, and load my html page with these data. However, the data I downloaded from the server does not get populated into the collection properly. The collection length is zero, do anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
(function ($) {
    window.Menu = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    window.MenuCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: window.Menu,
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'parse');
        },
        url: function(){
            return 'http://localhost:8080/testing/123';
        },
        parse : function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            // this prints:
            // "[{"name":"helloworld1"},{"name":"helloworld2"}]"

            this.add(resp);
            this.add(new Menu({name:"black perl"}));
            console.log(this);
            // the length of the object in the console log is 0
        }
    });

    window.MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html('<span>'+this.model.get('name')+'</span>');
            return this;
        }
    });

    window.MenuListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },
        render: function() {
            this.model.each(function(menu) {
                $(this.el).append(new MenuView({model:menu}).render().el);
            });

            return this;
        }
    });

    var view;
    AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("body"),
        initialize: function () {
            this.menus = new MenuCollection();
            this.menuListView = new MenuListView({model:this.menus});
            view = this.menuListView;
            this.menus.fetch({success: function(){console.log("success");
            console.log(view.render().el);}});
        },
        events: {

        }
    });

    var appview = new AppView;

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't see very much effort here in trying to simplify the example code. Could be helpful if you could show us a very smaller version of your code that reproduces the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) works:

> **parse** `collection.parse(response)`
>
> **parse** is called by Backbone whenever a collection's models are returned by the server, in fetch. The function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection.

So if you're getting `[{"name":"helloworld1"},{"name":"helloworld2"}]` from the server, you don't even need a `parse` implementation.

The strange behavior you're seeing with `add` is more interesting. If we look at [`fetch`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/0.9.2/backbone.js#L753), we see this:

```
fetch: function(options) {
  //...
  options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
    collection[options.add ? 'add' : 'reset'](collection.parse(resp, xhr), options);
    if (success) success(collection, resp);
  };
  //...
}
```

You're calling `fetch` without the `add` option set so things happen like this:

1. `collection.parse` is called.
2. Your `parse` adds a few things and calls `console.log`.
3. Your parse doesn't return anything at all.
4. `collection.reset` is called to add what `parse` returned.
5. `reset` will clear out the collection and then adds nothing because `parse` didn't return anything.

Some `console.log` implementations put a live reference in the console, that's why you get an empty collection in the console: `console.log(this)` ends up showing `this` *after* the `reset` call.

Comment: The code seems to have changed since this answer was written: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L873 What should we do now?

Comment: @qwertynl The bit about `add` was just an explanation of the seemingly strange behavior that they were seeing from `parse`. The meat of the answer is that no `parse` implementation was needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, another problem you have is that you are not passing "this" into the context of the for loop inside your view rendering. Thus, when you return the "el" element, your html page will be blank without the contents from the server.

Comment: And `MenuListView` should be working with `collection` rather than `model`.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the parse method as availble from backbone.js 0.9+
version 0.5.3 would not call parse.