# Backbone Model.save() kills all bindings to events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been using [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) on a new project and so far have loved it,  but I have come to a blocker that I can't seem to get around.

Without trying to explain my whole domain model, I have found that when you save a model, the response comes back from the server and gets parsed again, creating new sub objects and therefore breaking and event bindings I had previously put on the object.

For instance, if I save `ContentCollection` (its a Backbone.Model not a collection) when it comes back from the server, the response gets parsed and creates a new Collection in `this.contentItems`,  which breaks all the binding I had on `this.contentItems`. Is there any way to get around this?   Tell backbone not to parse the response somehow?  Grab the bindings off the original list, and then re-attach them to the new list?

```
App.ContentCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/collection',

    initialize: function() {
    },

    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        this.contentItems = new App.ContentList(resp.items)
        this.subscriptions = new App.SubscriptionList(resp.subscriptions)

        return resp
    },

    remove: function(model){
        this.contentItems.remove(model)
        this.save({'removeContentId':model.attributes.id})
    },

    setPrimaryContent: function(model){
        this.save({'setPrimaryContent':model.attributes.id})
    }
})
```

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is the way you're using the `parse()` method. Backbone just expects this method to take a server response and return a hash of attributes - *not* to change the object in any way. So Backbone calls `this.parse()` within `save()`, not expecting there to be any side-effects - but the way you've overridden `.parse()`, you're changing the model when the function is called.

The way I've dealt with this use case in the past is to initialize the collections when you first call `fetch()`, something like:

```
App.ContentCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.bind('change', initCollections, this);
    },

    initCollections: function() {
        this.contentItems = new App.ContentList(resp.items);
        this.subscriptions = new App.SubscriptionList(resp.subscriptions);
        // now you probably want to unbind it,
        // so it only gets called once
        this.unbind('change', initCollections, this)
    },

    // etc
});
```

Comment: `parse` is called by `fetch` and `fetch` does a `reset` after `parse` is called (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675974/479863). And congrats on the backbone.js bronze that you'll be picking up in a few hours.

Comment: @muistooshort - in that case too, `parse` is expected to be side-effect free (I think we're agreeing here). And thanks!

Comment: Yes, we are agreeing, `parse` is supposed to be a simple data transformer, the specific context in which it is used makes side effects a bad idea.